# Two ListFragments in One Activity

Tags: android-listfragment

Since each ListView is required to have android:id="android:id/list"... how can i make two listviews on two different fragments? .. the OnItemSelectListener seems to listen to events of the other fragment ... plz help

Comment: Are you using Fragments or ListFragments?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same situation... so far, my guess is that this is not possible since the app only takes into account the first ListView created (because android:id="android:id/list" must be unique in app scope) documentation does not state how to have a custom id, therefore my guess is on this case, ListFragment can't be used.